# Hash/Unhash function

Tags: python, function, hash

I have the following code. It is a hash function that turns a word into a hashed number:

```
def myHash (string):
    solution = 5
    alphabet = 'abcdegjkmnoprstuvwyz'

    for carac in string:
        solution = solution * 21 + alphabet.find(carac)
    return solution

test = 'mytest'
print (myHash(test))
```

How would I do the opposite way? From a hashed number and I have to guess the string.

Comment: Calling that hashing is IMHO wrong. Anyhow, without wanting to spoil your homework effort, analyze the values of the strings `'a', 'b', 'aa', 'ab', 'ba', 'bb'`.

Comment: Hint: `n / d == q * d + r` for unique values `q` and `0 <= r < d`.

Comment: You can't go the opposite way.

Comment: A hash cannot be unhashed by definition except by brute-force. The premise is wrong.

Comment: @deceze Hash cannot be unhashed in part because hash functions are not injective. We would have to figure out if that one has collisions. I think it does by the way, but I'm writing something to figure out.

Comment: I take it back, now that I realise that this isn't a hash function by any standard definition.  It is indeed trivially invertible (assuming we only consider inputs that consist of the characters in `alphabet`).

Comment: Is it normal that not all lowercases are present in your alphabet? Because str.find will return -1 for some of them...

Answer (score 0):

*Since this looks like a homework, as pointed out in the comments, I'm leaving writing the code to you.*

You cannot invert this hash function due to collisions. Namely, since not all lowercases are present in `alphabet`, then `str.find` will return `-1` for characters such as *f*, *h*, *i*, *l* and *q*.

So if you receive, for example, the hash `2204`, you cannot know if the input string was `'af'`, `'ah'`, `'ai'`, `'al'` or `'aq'`.

Although, this is a weird behaviour and almost seems like a mistake, so let's discuss the case where `alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz` and `solution = solution * 26 + alphabet.find(carac)`.

Then the index of the trailing character in `alphabet` is `num % 26`. You can then get the corresponding hash for the remaining characters by substraction and division and recursively obtain your string.

Answer (score -1):

I think you could try this logic:

```
 '''
 Given all variable in your original code
 '''
 1. Define variable(Your String):  testF, Hashed ="", myHash(test)
 2. loop , stop condition (You figure it out):
       testF=alphabet[int(Hashed%(len(alphabet)+1))]+testF
       Hashed=int((Hashed-Hashed%(len(alphabet)+1))//(len(alphabet)+1))
```